# Print argument of function that exceeds $RecursionLimit

Tags: warning-messages, recursion

Is there a way to print the argument of a function which results in a `$RecursionLimit::reclim` error?

As an example, cosider the code

```
fib[n_] := If[n == 1, 1, n*fib[n - 1]];
fib[5]
(* 120 *)
fib[1023]
(* $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. *)
```

the ideal output should be something like

*120*

*Recursion error for n=1023*

*$RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded.*

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function [`Check`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Check.html) is what you are looking for.

```
fib[n_] := 
  Check[If[n == 1, 1, n*fib[n - 1]], Print["n = ", n]; Abort[]]

Block[{$RecursionLimit = 20}, fib[25]]
```

> $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 20 exceeded. >>
>   n = 17
>
> ```
> $Aborted
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to restrict the input to be a positive integer. Since you are basically defining the factorial function, I have renamed it to factorial rather than fib.

```
factorial::argv = 
  "The argument `1` is not a positive integer.";

factorial[n_] /; If[
   TrueQ[Element[n, Integers] && n > 0], True,
   Message[factorial::argv, n]; False] :=
 Check[If[n == 1, 1, n*fib[n - 1]],
  StringForm[
   "Recursion error for n = ``", n],
  $RecursionLimit::reclim]

factorial[-5]
```

> factorial::argv: The argument -5 is not a positive integer.
>
> factorial[-5]

```
factorial[5]
```

> 120

```
factorial[1023]
```

> $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>
>
> Recursion error for n = 1023

Comment: Well, "fib" need not stand for "Fibonacci" (maybe that was the point of it being a fib).